# How to set FormGroup and FormControl at the ngOnInit() with Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, form-control

I have just started to learn **Angular** and old version should work:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core'
import {FormGroup, FormControl, Validators} from '@angular/forms'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login-page',
  templateUrl: './login-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login-page.component.css']
})
export class LoginPageComponent implements OnInit {

  form: FormGroup

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = new FormGroup(controls:{
      email: new FormControl(formState: null, validatorOrOpts: [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
      password: new FormControl(formState: null, validatorOrOpts: [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(minLength: 6)])
    })
  }

  onSubmit() {

  }

}
```

The errors:

```
Failed to compile.

src/app/login-page/login-page.component.ts:17:39 - error TS1005: ',' expected. this.form = new FormGroup(controls:{  

src/app/login-page/login-page.component.ts:18:39 - error TS1005: ',' expected. email: new FormControl(formState: null, validatorOrOpts: [Validators.required, Validators.email]),

src/app/login-page/login-page.component.ts:18:62 - error TS1005: ',' expected. email: new FormControl(formState: null, validatorOrOpts: [Validators.required, Validators.email]),

src/app/login-page/login-page.component.ts:19:42 - error TS1005: ',' expected. password: new FormControl(formState: null, validatorOrOpts: [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(minLength: 6)])

src/app/login-page/login-page.component.ts:19:65 - error TS1005: ',' expected. password: new FormControl(formState: null, validatorOrOpts: [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(minLength: 6)])

src/app/login-page/login-page.component.ts:19:119 - error TS1005: ',' expected. password: new FormControl(formState: null, validatorOrOpts: [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(minLength: 6)])
```

*Angular CLI: 10.2.0
Node: 14.11.0
OS: darwin x64*

Comment: `new FormGroup(controls:{ ...` does not seem to be a valid syntax.

Comment: @AndreiGătej I do the code from Udemy couse, but it was an old version of Angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `FormBuilder` to help with this

### Steps to Implement

- Inject `FormBuilder`

```typescript
constructor (private fb: FormBuilder) {}
```

- Call `.group()` function on the injected service to generate the `FormGroup`. This way you do not have to use `new` and everything works

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.form = this.fb.group({
    email: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
    password: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]]
  })
}
```

[See sample demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vwaee5)

Comment: **import {FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators} from '@angular/forms'**

Answer (score 0):

This answer is also correct according to the question and code. **Without** any **constructor**.

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core'
import {FormGroup, FormControl, Validators} from '@angular/forms'
```

Imports

```
  form: FormGroup

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      email: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
      password: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)])
    })
  }
```

Code